# Hide meridians and parallel lines from plot and add TICK marks in matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I want to hide the meridian and parallel lines from my plot and add the tick marks. 
I could remove the lines by setting `linewidth=0`, but how to add the tick marks with each Lat-Lon label.

```
meridians = np.arange(70.,90.,0.5)
m.drawmeridians(meridians,labels=[0,0,0,1],fontsize=9, linewidth=0)
```

Comment: Have you used set_yticks() and set_xticks()?  http://matplotlib.org/1.5.1/faq/howto_faq.html?highlight=ticks#configure-the-tick-linewidths

Comment: No, I haven't used this as I am working with spatial plots. After your reply I included it as `ax.set_xticks((70.,90.,0.5))` but it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

`ax.set_xticks([0,1,2])` worked in my case.

You might also want to try `suppress_ticks = False`, see
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18363987/basemap-how-to-remove-actual-lat-lon-lines-while-keeping-the-ticks-on-the-axis